# How not to assume that your data will be stored in files

Tags: requirements

How would you formulate software requirements without saying: "The software has to know the filename of the configuration file."? You don't know yet if the configuration data will be held in a file a database or whatever may be decided later. So how would you generically refer to the address of this location without introducing technical constraints?

Comment: "The program locates the required configuration settings". See, no mention of files.

Answer (score 1):

The configuration settings for the software should be stored external to the application, and the application should be able to access the external settings.